# Questions regarding solvability $Ax=w$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Dear mathstack exchange,

Currently I`m working on my bachelor thesis. I want to answer the following:

1. $Ax=w$ is solveable in $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if
   $\mbox{det}(A) \bmod (p-1) \in (\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

(already answered thanks to aRaRa)

2. How to deal with zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ for $Ax=w$

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only about the additional case, when we don't know that $\det A$ is invertible modulo $p-1$. I am addressing the problem in aRaRa's second answer, where multiplying the system by $\mathrm{adj}\, A$ occasionally introduces unwanted solutions. Possibly many of them.

We can think of $A$ as having integer entries (for a little while - bear with me). I intend to use the so called Smith normal form. It says that there exists square matrices 
with integer entries $P$ and $Q$ such that
$$
A=PDQ,
$$
where

- $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $d_1,d_2,\ldots$ such that $d_i\mid d_{i+1}$ for all applicable $i$, and
- the matrices $P$ and $Q$ are unimodular, i.e. they have inverses with integer entries as well (in other words their determinants are $\pm1$).

The system $Ax=w$ is thus equivalent to the system $PDQx=w$. Because of unimodularity $P^{-1}$ and $Q^{-1}$ also make sense over the ring $\Bbb{Z}_n, n=p-1$. Therefore the original system is equivalent to the system of congruences
$$
DQx\equiv P^{-1}w\pmod n.\qquad(*)
$$
How can we all the solutions of the system of linear congruences $(*)$? We need to introduce a helper set of new variable $y$ defined by $y=Qx$. Because $Q$ is unimodular as well the correspondence $y=Qx$ is bijective (Sorry about playing Capt'n Bbvious here - $Q$ is invertible modulo $n$). So if we can find all the vectors $y$, we can find all the solution vectors $x$ as well.

But the remaining system 
$$
Dy=P^{-1}w
$$
has a diagonal matrix of coefficients! There we can find all the solutions of all the components $y$ with the method in aRaRa's 2nd answer. It is possible that there are none, but them's the breaks.

---

As an example consider the congruence from aRaRa's 1st answer
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rr}5&5\\-1&1\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{r}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right)\equiv\left(\begin{array}{r}1\\11\end{array}\right)\pmod{12}.
$$
Here
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}5&5\\-1&1\end{array}\right)
=P\left(\begin{array}{rr}1&0\\0&10\end{array}\right)Q
$$
with the unimodular matrices
$$
P=\left(\begin{array}{rr}5&1\\1&0\end{array}\right),\qquad
Q=\left(\begin{array}{rr}-1&1\\1&0\end{array}\right).
$$
Let's write 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{r}y_1\\y_2\end{array}\right)=
Q\left(\begin{array}{r}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}x_2-x_1\\x_1\end{array}\right).
$$
We have
$$
P^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{r}1\\11\end{array}\right)\equiv\left(\begin{array}{r}11\\6\end{array}\right)\pmod{12},
$$
so we want to solve the pair of congruences 
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcr}y_1&\equiv& 11\\10y_2&\equiv& 6\end{array}\right.$$
both modulo $12$. Clearly we must have $y_1\equiv 11\equiv-1$, but for $y_2$ we get two possibilities $y_2\equiv3$ and $y_2\equiv -3\equiv9$. Given that $x_1\equiv y_2$ and $x_2\equiv y_1+y_2$ this leads to the two solutions $(x_1,x_2)\equiv(3,2)$ and $(x_1,x_2)\equiv(9,8)$.

Comment: Note that we don't need to get to the proper Smith normal form. Namely we did not need the divisibility property $d_\mid d_{i+1}$ of the diagonal entries. As long as $D$ is diagonal and $P$ and $Q$ are unimodular, the logic of the method checks out.

Answer (score 2):

But "if ***and only if***" is wrong.

Let $p=13$, so $q:=p-1=12$.

Look at the following linear equation in $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$:
$$\pmatrix{5 & 5\\11 & 1}\, x=\pmatrix{1\\11}\,, $$
it has the solution
$$w=\pmatrix{3\\2} \, ,$$
but
$$\det \pmatrix{5 & 5\\11 & 1} = 10\not\in (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times=\{1,5,7,11\} \, .$$

The "if" part (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Inverses)):

\begin{align}
A\, x & = w\\
\mathrm{adj}(A) A \, x &= \mathrm{adj}(A) \,w \\
\det(A)\cdot E\, x &= \mathrm{adj}(A) \, w\\
x &= \det(A)^{-1}\mathrm{adj}(A) \, w\, .
\end{align}
$E$ is simply the identity matrix here. I could divide the equation by $\det(A)$ because we stipulated that $\det(A)$ is in the unit group of the ring.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding how to deal with zero divisors:

Do all the steps as in my first answer till you get to this:
$$\det(A)\cdot E\, x = \mathrm{adj}(A) \, w$$
Now since you can't simply divide by $\det(A)$, what can we do?

This equation is just a system of many simple equations with ***one variable*** ($N=\dim(A)$):
\begin{align} 
\mathrm{1.} \quad \det(A) \, x_1 & \equiv \bigl(\mathrm{adj}(A)\, w\bigr)_1 \bmod{(p-1)} \\
\mathrm{2.} \quad \det(A) \, x_2 & \equiv \bigl(\mathrm{adj}(A)\, w\bigr)_2 \bmod{(p-1)} \\
&\vdots \\
\mathrm{N.} \quad \det(A) \, x_N & \equiv \bigl(\mathrm{adj}(A)\, w\bigr)_N \bmod{(p-1)} \\
\end{align}

How can we solve them?

You can use the following theorem:

> The equation $$  a x \equiv b \bmod{n} \; \quad a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\, , n \in \mathbb{N}
> $$ with $d:= \gcd(a,n)$ has no solution if $d \nmid b$. But if $d \mid b$, it is ***equivalent*** to $$
>   x \equiv y \frac{b}{d} \bmod{\frac{n}{d}}
> $$ with $y\in \mathbb{Z}$ chosen so, that $y a + z n = d$ for a $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

You get $y$ (and $z$) by the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Just solve them one after another with this theorem and you're done!

Of course the equation doesn't need to have a solution, which happens if there is a $k \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$ for which the greatest common divisor of $\det(A)$ and $p-1$ doesn't divide $\bigl(\mathrm{adj}(A)\, w\bigr)_k$.

Comment: I love you! Great comment!

Comment: Getting that $\det A$ to appear there may introduce extra solutions (IOW your system is not always equivalent to the original one). To drive this point home consider the toy case of $p=5$, $$A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&2&0\cr0&0&2\cr}.$$ We have that $\det A=4\equiv0\pmod{p-1}$. But modulo $4$ the first variable is uniquely determined and the other two have two possibilities (or none).

Comment: Or in other words, multiplying both sides by $\mathrm{adj} A$ does not result in an equivalent system.

Comment: I think that going via Smith normal form (first on the integer side to make sure it exists) should work. Thinking it through :-)

Comment: Yeah. It does pan out. I decided to reuse the example from your 1st answer (+1 was there). Another solution also came out. Together with the conclusion that the pair of congruences has exactly two solutions.